# How to add 2 imageviews in layout dynamically in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am developing the Android app in which i want to add 2 imagview at time in layout.The flow is in layout there is one imageview added for taking photo via camera when user take photo from camera when I get the image from camera I will show it in that imageview and that imageview has one cross ImageButton on it's right corner which will get visible when image gets loaded and same thing will happen for another imageview which i want to add when user click photo but i dont know how to add this dynamically. I search for answer but there is only one imageview is added in the layout.Please help me out with this issue.

i want it like this
[as show in this image the imageview has cross button on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY6iJ.png)

as per the solution given by Vijendra i updated my xml and java code but having 
error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup

here is my `main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bicycle_broken_layout">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_moreinfo_broken_bike"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/more_info"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:background="@color/ch_bg"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:lines="3"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/broken_image_photos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_moreinfo_broken_bike"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_submit_report"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/broken_image_photos"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/bg_main"
        android:text="@string/submit_button"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="15dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is `mainactivity.java`

```
public class Broken_Report_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {

private EditText broken_bike_number,broken_bike_location,more_info;
private Button barcode_scanner,location;
private Button submit_report;
private CheckBox seat,pedals,breaks,lock,chain,tier;
private Imageview_add_dynamically photo1,close_photo,framlayout;
RelativeLayout broken_image_layout;
private boolean Isphoto1=false,Isphoto2=false,Isphoto3=false;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_broken_report);

    broken_bike_number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_broken_bike_number);
    broken_bike_location = 
    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_broken_bike_location);
    more_info = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_moreinfo_broken_bike);

    submit_report = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_report);

    seat = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_seat);
    lock = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_lock);
    chain = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_chain);
    breaks = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_break);
    pedals = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_pedals);
    tier = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.ch_tire);

    broken_image_layout =
    (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.broken_image_photos);

    broken_image_layout.addView(photo1);
    broken_image_layout.addView(close_photo);

    photo1.setOnClickListener(this);
    close_photo.setOnClickListener(this);

    submit_report.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.broken_img1:
            Intent broken_imag_1 = new 
            Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(broken_imag_1,CAMERA_REQUEST);
            break;

        case R.id.broken_img1_close:
            broken_image_layout.removeView(photo1);
            broken_image_layout.removeView(close_photo);
            break;

        case R.id.btn_submit_report:
            break;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        photo1.getImgPhoto().setImageBitmap(photo);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post a picture of what you want. Probably you should use `RelativeLayout` to add 2 `ImageView`s. What do you want: a code?

Comment: i updated my question @CoolMind i want it same way but dynamically

Comment: Make a RelativeLayout, place there ImageView with topmargin (a photo) and in a right top corner another ImageView (a cross). If you want to show only photo, set visibility of a cross to INVISIBLE or GONE. When you want to show a cross, set its visibility to VISIBLE. Add onClick events.

Comment: @CoolMind for the Initial ImageView i did as you suggested but for 2nd time when this ImageView will get added dynamically then how can i add the 2nd ImageView at right corner of the 1st Imageview in java code

Answer (score 1):

In Your xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/multipleimages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            //add your imageview here programatically
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

In Java code

```
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.multipleimages);
        ImageView imageView1=//your image 1
        ImageView imageView2=//your image 2

        ll.addView(imageView1);
        ll.addView(imageView2);
```

Comment: I did this but how do i set the second ImageView to the right corner of the 1st ImageView in java code

Comment: I think you want cross button at top of image view

Comment: yes exactly which is shown in mentioned image in question.

Comment: wait I am writing your solution

Comment: https://code4read.com/android/add-dynamic-image-view-cross-button-top-right-side/

Comment: i will implement your code and will report here Thanks for this solution @Vijendra Kumar Sewaliya

Comment: Hi i implemented your code in my application but i got error like this
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add a null child view to a ViewGroup